# Issues understanding the multinomial theorem and its multiindex notation

Tags: combinatorics, summation, products, index-notation, multinomial-theorem

$$(x_1+x_2+...+x_m)^n=\sum_{(k_1 + k_2 +... +k_m) \ = \ n} {n \choose k_1,k_2...k_m} \prod^m_{t=1}x_t^{k_t}$$
Let's do $(a+b+c)^3$. That means $a =x_1, b =x_2, c=x_3=x_m$. The multiindex below the sigma function is the different $P_m$ partitions of $n$, consisting of summands $\ge0$. If $n =3$, then those partitions will be $3+0+0$, $2+1+0$ and $1+1+1$. That means that the following operations after the sigma needs to use all of those *k*-values. So, the summation will look like this:
$${3\choose 3,0,0} \times a^3 \times b^0 \times c^0$$
$$+$$
$${3 \choose 2,1,0} \times a^2 \times b^1 \times c^0$$
$$+$$
$${3 \choose 1,1,1} \times a^1 \times b^1 \times c^1$$
$$=a^3 + 3a^2b + 6abc$$
But that's obviously wrong, as it's missing $b^3 + c^3 + 3a^2c + 3b^2a + 3b^2c + 3c^2a + 3c^2b$. Thing is, I can't see how the formula above is to be used any other way that the erroneous way I used it. This is how I've interpreted it:

> Since the *x* has the same index as it's exponent, the order is stuck, which means instead of going through every combination of the $x_i^{k_i}$, it will only get the first $x$ raised to the first $k$th power, the second $x$ raised to the second $k$th power, and so on. This misses a lot of the summands. How have I misinterpreted the notation to produce this wrong algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order is important for these partitions. So you would need to have a term for every partition below:

- $3+0+0$
- $0+3+0$
- $0+0+3$
- $1+2+0$
- $2+1+0$
- $0+1+2$
- $0+2+1$
- $1+0+2$
- $2+0+1$
- $1+1+1$

Think of it as saying the more cumbersome

$$\sum_{\substack{(k_1,\cdots,k_m) \in \Bbb Z_{\ge 0}^m \\ k_1 + \cdots + k_m = n}}$$

Comment: Yeah, I know I have to have the different permutations of the partitions, but my problem is that I can't see how the equation tells me to factor in these permutations. Is it a rule of multiindices that whatever partition they describe, one is to iterate over every permutation of that partition? If so, I understand the equation.

Comment: I honestly wouldn't know. I've only encountered multi-indices myself when dealing with this exact equation

Comment: Ah I see. Well, I'll take your word that this is how the multiindex is used in this scenario then, as that's the only way the equation can give the answer, and then I'll be looking for the convention for how to use multiindices generally.